# Redirect Rule for All Requests that Come with A Specific Server Alias

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, fedora, rewrite

I am trying to write a redirect rule that will send all incoming requests directed at given server alias. Below is what my .conf file looks like. I am having problems with the first rule associated with foo.com. The rewrite for requests with the alias foo.com simply does not happen. I am not even sure how to debug this...

```
    NameVirtualHost xxx.xx.x.194
    <VirtualHost xxx.xx.x.194>
     ServerName foo.com
      ServerAlias www.foo.com

      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cgi-bin/redirect.py?url=spencer [L,QSA,PT]
      SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1
      SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
    </VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost xxx.xx.x.194>
     ServerName bar.com
     ServerAlias www.bar.com

     Include /etc/httpd/conf.d/zumodo.common

     ErrorLog logs/zumodo_errors_log
     CustomLog logs/zumodo_log combined
      SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1
      SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Are you saying you want the rewrite to happen on requests to `foo.com`, but not to `www.foo.com`?  Or to both?  If it's both, then that looks fine; try setting a `RewriteLog` and turn up `RewriteLogLevel 9`.

Comment: I want to rewrite to both. Where do I set RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel and where will the logs be?

Comment: note I am using etc/http/conf/http.conf

Comment: Also when I add this command, nothing get logged to this log...

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
RewriteRule /?(.*) /cgi-bin/redirect.py?url=spencer [L,QSA,PT]
```

For debugging, try adding:

```
RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cgi-bin/redirect.py?url=spencer [L,QSA,PT]
```

means: "redirect all the requests to `/cgi-bin/redirect.py?url=spencer`"

Is that what you actually want to do?

If no, please give two examples of Incoming URLs and how they should be transformed.

Anyway here are my 2 usual hints:

### Two hints:

---

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)